# Angular RouterLink queryParamsHandling for optional params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a clean way to merge the current optional queryParams with an additional optional queryParam on a link in the template?

Current url: `/search;brand=Trek`

Desired goto link: `/search;brand=Trek;start=1` (startCount will be incremented)

I know Angular supports the ability to merge **normal** queryParams (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html), but I don't think it works with **optional** queryParams.

That's why this doesn't work:

```
<a class="nav-btn"
   queryParamsHandling="merge"
   [routerLink]="[ { start: startCount+1 } ]">
    Next Page
</a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding { preserveQueryParams: true }

Comment: This is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<a class="nav-btn"
   queryParamsHandling="preserve" <--- instead of 'merge'
   [routerLink]="[ { start: startCount+1 } ]">
    Next Page
</a>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't seem to work. It got rid of all of the previous params and added the new start param.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the latest release of Angular, so here's my workaround solution:

Subscribe and save the params:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    for(let param in params){
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(param)){
            console.log('param:', param);
            this.currentParams[param] = params[param];
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Then add additional optional params to currentParam object:

```
this.currentParams.start = this.startCount+1;
```

And re-navigate to your route with all the params:

```
this.router.navigate([ 'search', this.currentParams ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

for preserving and merging on existing query params:

`<a class="nav-btn" preserveQueryParams [routerLink]="['/yourRoute']"  [queryParams]="{start: startCount+1}"></a>
<a class="nav-btn" mergeQueryParams [routerLink]="['/yourRoute']" [queryParams]="{start: startCount+1}"></a>`